# Testing Payable Functions From Truffle

Tags: truffle, payable

I'm trying to test a payable function from Truffle my function looks like so:

```
function recordOrder(bytes32 orderNumber) payable returns(bool success) {
    if(msg.value==0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(!orderStructs[orderNumber].exists) {
        orderStructs[orderNumber].sender = msg.sender;
        orderStructs[orderNumber].amountReceived = msg.value;
        orderStructs[orderNumber].exists = true;
    }
    else {
        orderStructs[orderNumber].amountReceived += msg.value;
    }

    LogOrder(msg.sender, orderNumber, msg.value);
    withdrawFee(msg.value, orderNumber);
    return true;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to send payments to a function but I'm confused on how.  If I call the function like so:

```
var facilitator;
OrdersFacilitator.deployed().then(x => facilitator = x);

var orderNumber = '33075588-8408-484b-8a53-e9c7f61bcb12';
facilitator.recordOrder.call(orderNumber);
```

I get a return value of false which make sense considering I don't think I've specified an amount to send.  However when I call the function directly:

```
facilitator.recordOrder(orderNumber);
```

I'm returned some json with a reciept:

```
{ tx: '0x5e38d5bb4f933a58e56620e8b0ae9ae0acb191b92ce0fef2f8fe784c9d40ef2c',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash: '0x5e38d5bb4f933a58e56620e8b0ae9ae0acb191b92ce0fef2f8fe784c9d40ef2c',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x038a57ce4a73efc59d57403d652119d3114602311756251be74e75cbe4d06e39',
     blockNumber: 5,
     gasUsed: 24150,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 24150,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: 1 },
  logs: [] }
```

Which I have no idea what is going on here, because I never specified an amount, and I'm calling from the truffle console, So I don't even know how gas when I'm not connected to an account (that I know of).

How can I send value to my payable function from truffle?

Comment: try this `facilitator.recordOrder.call(orderNumber, {value: 100 });` to specify an amount

Comment: I don't think you want `.call()` or it wont actually write to the blockchain, right?

Comment: I'm mostly just trying to figure out if my contract works, What does call do is that just a mock?

Comment: `.call` will simulate the function call, and do things locally. It is good for testing a positive result, but does not actually send a transaction or update the contract state. For example, it would return `true` or `false` based on your function, but not actually `LogOrder` or `withdrawFee`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Web3 offers a number of optional parameters which you can add to a function call:

- `from` - The address transactions should be made from.
- `gasPrice` - The gas price in wei to use for transactions.
- `gas` - The maximum gas provided for a transaction (gas limit).
- `value` - The value transferred for the transaction in Wei, also the endowment if it's a contract-creation transaction.

[etc...](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction)

To use them, simply include them as an object as the last parameter in your function call:

```
facilitator.recordOrder(orderNumber, {value: web3.toWei(2, 'ether')});
```

Comment: I'm using console in truffle, accounts is not defined, How do I link to accounts[0]?

Comment: If you do not define `from` it will automatically pick the account loaded (`accounts[0]`), but if you want access to the other accounts available from your web provider, you can do something like `var accounts; web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err,res) { accounts = res; });`

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work I get an error when I try to call `web3.eth.getAccounts()` callback is not a function

Comment: See minor update to include a callback function. FYI, I was short handing things, but you should be very familiar with [error first callback functions](https://shawntabrizi.com/crypto/making-web3-js-work-asynchronously-javascript-promises-await/) if you are playing with Web3. It is pretty common people will shorthand, and you will need to make sure you are always implementing the asynchronous versions of the functions.

Comment: Thanks, that new edit worked, So I marked it correct.  Still a bit confused on how this works, I never mapped any accounts nor secret, So  how does web3 have an account either ether to send?

Comment: I assume you have something like [ganache](https://truffleframework.com/ganache) running as a local blockchain? Ganache will create 10 accounts for you to play with each with 100 ETH to start, all locally of course. Truffle connects to this local blockchain as a part of your migration script.

Comment: oh so it automatically maps those accounts for me, Thanks for all your help you cleared up all of my confusion!

Answer (score 3):

Update: With web3 1.0 the **web3.toWei** is no longer available, rather **web3.utils.toWei**